# How to get the thread running time in java using thread ID?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

My goal is to display all thread with their running times in browser. Here is my code block.

```
ThreadInfo[] infoThreads = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().dumpAllThreads(true, true);
for (int i = infoThreads.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (infoThreads[i].getThreadName().contains("http")) {
        if (infoThreads[i].getThreadState() != State.WAITING && infoThreads[i].getThreadState() != State.TIMED_WAITING) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to use java code to execute some command like " top -H -p <pid> " to get the running time.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options... (from top of my head now)

1 - Store date during application startup and compare it with actual time when you get threads. Compare start app time and current time and you have runtime. But it is not a best option.

2 - **Thread class instrumentation**. This one is what I would try for first time.
Create an `Agent` class with Instrumentation, implementation of `ClassFileTransformer`, in `transform` method check name of class and catch `Thread` class and modify bytecode to store time of thread startup. You can use Javassist for that. I think `init` method in Thread class is a good spot to place `startDate` variable and store this information there.

When I'll have time, I'll prepare example code of that.